# Сколько звуков в слове ЕНОТ?

Tags: фонетика, учебное-задание

В слове Енот сколько звуков - 4 или 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, 5, потому что буква "е" в начале слова обозначает два звука

Comment: Спасибо. )Я уже сама догадалась. ))

Comment: Тогда примите ответ, кликнув на значок.